# Unable to turn on WiFi on Nokia Lumia 920

Tags: 8.0, nokia-lumia-920, 8.1-update-1

i have a Nokia Lumia 920 i just got it since two days ago, originally it came with WP8 and i upgraded it to WP8.1 then my WIFI settings stopped working, by stopped working i mean:

When i go to:
Menu -> Setting -> WI-FI

I am not able to see the options of the WI-FI and i get redirected again to the menu, is like if the WI-FI button doesn't work, i have already performed soft and hard resets and now i am back using WP8 (downgrade) and still doesn't work.

So i can only use it with my carrier data but cannot turn on the WIFI due this problem.

I will be happy to get any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried re-installing the OS using the Windows Phone Recovery Tool?

Comment: I surely haven't because i have no idea on how to do that, do you have any link that explains how to do that properly? That might help.

Comment: This tool will flash the latest availiable regular update onto your device
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA142987

Comment: A hard reset might be easier, and can be got to via **settings** > **about** > [ reset your phone ]

Comment: @RowlandShaw, I already tried by using that method, it hard reset the phone however seem it doesn't downgrade the OS to its original version, since previously it was working fine with the last OS version i guess it has some compatibility issue, i am trying the downgrade and will let you know what happened. Thanks Guys!

Comment: @Thomas, thanks to your hint i was able to figure out the problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Solve this problem is necessary to install in your PC the NSU (Nokia software Updater), this program will allow you to get the latest WP 8.1 version which includes a lot of fixes, i didn't have to downgrade to make it work.

The first step is to get the NSU, download it from http://nds2.fds-fire.nokia.com/fds_fire/1310/0909/7297834135/NokiaSoftwareUpdaterForRetail_4.1.0.exe

I found extremely useful the next link which explains how to do it properly: 
http://winphonemetro.com/2014/03/actualizar-nokia-lumia-a-gdr3-black
(i know is in Spanish but you can always use a translator, besides the process in pretty much intuitive so you shouldn't have any problems).

It worked at the first time i tried, by doing this i solved the problem my phone had with the wireless drivers and still was able to keep the 8.1 OS version.

If you're having this or any other sort of issues with your Nokia i highly recommend you to do this, get the latest upgrades and enjoy of your smartphone!